# Breaking out of a recursive query in Postgres 11

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm having some trouble getting the correct data out of a tree structure, where I only want the first nodes in a branch matching criteria to be the result of the query.

I have this table of domains:

```
create table domains(
    id bigint,
    domain_name varchar,
    parent_id bigint,
    valid boolean
)

insert into domains values
    (1, 'example.com', null, false),
    (2, 'a.example.com', 1, true),
    (3, 'b.example.com', 1, false),
    (4, 'c.b.example.com', 3, true),
    (5, 'd.a.example.com', 2, true)
```

This gives this tree, with the valid domains in green:

[image: domain graph]

Based on this, I want `a.example.com` and `c.b.example.com` to be returned as valid domains. Had the top level domain `example.com` been valid, only that should be returned. ("valid" is just a flag determined elsewhere.)

I have a recursive query that fetches the whole domain tree:

```
WITH RECURSIVE valid_domains AS (
  SELECT id, domain_name, valid FROM domains
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT d.id, d.domain_name, d.valid FROM domains d
  JOIN valid_domains vd ON d.parent_id = vd.id
)
SELECT * FROM valid_domains
```

...but then my stumbling block is figuring out how to filter on valid domains and break that branch when I hit one that's valid, without returning any valid domains below it.

I've looked at window functions, but haven't been able to mesh that with the recursive query thus far. Am I taking the wrong approach by making this recursive in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id, domain_name, valid 
  FROM domains
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT domains.id, domains.domain_name, domains.valid 
  FROM domains
  JOIN cte ON domains.parent_id = cte.id
  WHERE NOT cte.valid -- stop recursion when valid node reached
)

SELECT id, domain_name
FROM cte
WHERE valid
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9f993e582d957df8f2219c1c317886fa)

Answer (score -3):

You were almost there:

```
WITH RECURSIVE valid_domains AS (
  SELECT id, domain_name, valid FROM domains
  WHERE parent_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT d.id, d.domain_name, d.valid FROM domains d
  JOIN valid_domains vd ON d.parent_id = vd.id
)
SELECT *
FROM valid_domains
WHERE valid
LIMIT 1;
```

I suppose you need to filter only valid answer and then just use `LIMIT` to get only the first result...

You might want to add an `ORDER BY` clause, though...

Comment: The author needs ALL valid roots, not only one.